# How to get this integral?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, fourier-series

Could someone explain how to the integral is obtained from the following equation.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n  \sin\left(\frac{n \pi v}{l}\right)=  x(x-l)$$
 where $ 0 \le x \le l$.

Integrate the above with limits $0$ to $l$

The next line of working after the one above was, $$B_n = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l} v(v-l)\sin\left(\frac{n \pi v}{l}\right) \operatorname d v$$

I dont understand how they get that line, it looks like they did a subsitution of $x = v$ ? But what about the summation and why is the sin not dividing the $v(v-l)$.

Could someone explain the steps between starting from that equation to getting that integral please.

Thank you

Comment: What do you know about Fourier series?

Comment: @SewerKeeper Thank you ! I completely forgot that topic, I just revised it and was able to solve the question !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that (Prove it by yourself!)

$$\int_{-l}^{l}{\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}dx}=\begin{cases} 0, & m\neq n; \\
l, & m=n.\end{cases}$$

Now you fix a positive integer, say $m$. Then in the integral

$$\int_{-l}^{l}{\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}}\right)dx}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int_{-l}^{l}{B_n\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}dx}}$$

all the terms with $n\neq m$ are equal to $0$! That is, it collapses to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int_{-l}^{l}{B_n\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}dx}}=\int_{-l}^{l}{B_m\sin^2\frac{m\pi x}{l}dx}=B_m\int_{-l}^{l}{\sin^2\frac{m\pi x}{l}dx}=B_m\cdot l.$$

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}}=x(l-x).$$

It follows that

$$\int_{-l}^{l}{x(l-x)\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}dx}=\int_{-l}^{l}{\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}}\right)dx}=B_m\cdot l.$$

Therefore,

$$B_m=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}{x(l-x)\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}dx}=\frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}{x(l-x)\sin\frac{m\pi x}{l}dx},$$

as $x(l-x)\sin(m\pi x/l)$ is odd.

Comment: I don't think necessary to recall the theory of Fourier series to apply it (besides the fact that your enthousiasm is sympathetic : "all the terms with m \ne n$ are equal to 0!")